# click to reveal and removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been reading through some guides and some posts on here but cant seem to put it all together for my situation, I haven't played with Jquery for such a long time ive forgotten how it all works.

I have an image .toggle-plus which when clicked should reveal the content within .hide and also change the image class to .toggle-minus.

My layout is like so

```
<div class="widget-header">
 <h3 class="title">Header 1</h3>
  <span class="toggle-plus"></span>
 </div>

 <address class="vcard hide">
  <!--Content Here-->
 </address>



<div class="widget-header">
 <h3 class="title">Header 2</h3>
  <span class="toggle-plus"></span> 
</div>

<div class="share-items hide">
  <!--content here -->
</div>


<div class="widget-header">
 <h3 class="title">Header 3</h3>
  <span class="toggle-plus"></span>
 </div>
<ul class="opening-hours hide">
 <!--content here -->
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.hide {
 display:none
}

.toggle-plus {
    background-image:url('/assets/toggle-open.png');
width:38px;
height:38px;
position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-minus {
background-image:url('/assets/toggle-close.png');
width:38px;
height:38px;
position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Could anyone help me on this one and explain the process, feel like im learning Jquery again

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to:

```
$('.widget-header').on('click', '.toggle-plus, .toggle-minus' function(e){
  // you can toggle class names here
  $(this).parents('.widget-header:eq(0)').next('.hide').slideToggle();
});
```

It would be a lot easier if you can combine your html so that there's more of a structural relationship between the hidden DIVs and the headers etc.